# Chrome's Dev console doesn't post console.log("message")when page is loaded from localhost (XAMPP Apache Server)

Tags: google-chrome, xampp, console.log

I am running a simple jQuery code (developing a simple webpage), while following a YouTube jQuery & Ajax tutorial. Half way of the tutorial, I was running the *index.html*  file directly from my PC folder on Google Chrome, and *console.log("message")* worked fine, posting the "*message*" on Chrome Dev console.

Getting into Ajax territory, the tut suggests running a local Apache Server with XAMPP.

Here is the problem, as the same code doesn't post anything on Chrome Dev console when the *index.html* is running from localhost throught XAMPP.

[PrtSCR of the page loaded from *localhost* (left) and from *file* (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqhqH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching I finally found what the problem was!
It was a browser cache issue! (I use Chrome)
So I  disabled Chrome Dev cache, and it works fine!
Anonther solution that I found is Cache Killer extension for Chrome, that clears the browsers cache in every page refresh.